# How to calculate the correlation by the Spearman method for each quantile of the quantile regression in R?

Tags: spearman-rho, quantile-regression

I'm trying to calculate the **Spearman's correlation coefficient for each quantile of my quantile regression** (to later calculate the R² of each quantile), but the package I know of (QCSIS) uses Pearson's correlation. So my idea was to try to separate the quantiles and use the `cor` function to manually find the correlations.

To check if the values ​​are correct, I thought of using the QCSIS package function as a way to check the results. I calculated Pearson's correlation using the package in question and then I did the same by separating the data and using the `cor` function, but the values ​​were different at the end.
Could anyone tell me why?

Example code:
`cor1` and `cor2` are different.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Method 1
cars_quant <- cars %>% 
  mutate(quantile = ntile(speed, 9)) %>% 
  group_by(quantile) %>%
  summarize(correlation = cor(x = speed, y = dist,
                              method = "pearson")) 

cor1 <- cars_quant$correlation

# Method 2
library(QCSIS)
qs <- 1:9/10 
cor2 <- qc(y = cars$dist, x = cars$speed, tau = qs)$rho

# print both
cor1
cor2
```

Output:

```r
> cor1
[1]  0.41440951 -0.58283514  0.72063396 -0.36642744 -0.18308346  0.36548170 -0.39123040  0.05675958 -0.21557348

> cor2
[1] 0.5169284 0.5862724 0.6091363 0.7041367 0.7156306 0.6763418 0.6239933 0.5484484 0.4791043
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methodology QCSIS comes from [Robust model-free feature screening via quantile correlation](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmva.2015.10.010). It uses the quantile correlation (QC) proposed by [Li et al.](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2014.892007), given by
$$
\text{qcor}_\tau(Y,Z) = \frac{\text{qcov}_\tau(Y,Z)}{\sqrt{\text{var}\{\psi_\tau(Y-Q_{\tau,Y}) \}\text{var}(Z)}}=\frac{\text{E}\{\psi_\tau(Y-Q_{\tau,Y})(Z-\text{E}(Z)\}}{\sqrt{(\tau-\tau^2)\text{var}(Z)}},
$$
where $\psi_\tau(u) = \tau - I(u < 0)$. It's not Pearson's correlation.